# Terminal command run in Python doesn't give expected results

Tags: python, terminal, raspberry-pi3

I want to run following command in terminal: `sudo service motion start`.

If I do that by myself, it will work fine - the camera is going to stream on specific port. But, if I run it in Python with: `os.system("sudo service motion start")`, it will still start service at specific port but won't show stream of the camera - it will show gray picture with counting date and time.

Some other options such as `subprocess.call()` didn't work either.

I would like to run that particular command from Python. I don't mind if terminal window opens (and closes afterwards), but it would be the best case if it doesn't open and command simply runs somewhere in background.

Comment: How are you running the python script?

Comment: I simply open it and run in IDLE.

Comment: Try running `python scriptname.py` from a terminal.

Comment: Interestingly enough, it worked. May you give a bit of detail why is it this way, in case someone sees this answer in the future?

Comment: I don't know much about IDLE, but it sounds like it has its own built-in terminal that doesn't work like a real terminal emulator.